# Apply custom function to groups of rows from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am developing a financial application. The goal is to calculate various portfolio risk statistics. The first basic problem is this:
I have a dataset with thousands of rows that have the following structure

```
Instrument  Factor  Weight
A           F1      0.149386064
A           F2      0.282444926
A           F300    0.66216264
B           F1      0.501194572
B           F2      0.037874843
B           F300    0.939051411
```

For each instrument in the dataframe I need to calculate systematic risk by using matrix multiplication of multiplying instrument weights by covariance matrix that is represented by BlockMatrix.

The actual calculation is not difficult and I have that part done. My question is what is the most efficient Scala/Spark way of performing the calculation of group of records for each instrument.

Basically I need something that can be expressed as

`instrument_df.groupBy("Instrument").agg(CalculateRisk)` where CalculateRisk has a reference to the covariance matrix and takes the rows of weights for each instrument

Comment: You probably want to implement a UDAF (User Defined Aggregate Function)